# Conditionally modify selection content with D3

Tags: d3.js

First of, I am still very new to D3 so this might just end up being a noob question.

I am trying to make a simple table with D3, in which I want to add either `text` or `innerHtml` within a `td` element. I am currently appending the element(`td`) to the dom, then based on its data I change either its inner text or html, all inside the `each` function. This does what I want but feels very hacky.

This is what my code looks like:

```
cells.enter()
.append("td")
    .each(function(d){
      if(d.isText()){
         d3.select(this).text(d.text);
      } else if(d.isInnerHtml()){
         d3.select(this).innerHtml(d.innerHtml);
      })
    });
```

I have omitted the code showing the data binding, let me know if that is required.

Comment: Why don't you use `.innerHtml()` for everything?

Comment: Thanks @Lars Kotthoff . Feeling really silly right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LarsKotthoff pointed out, I just used innerHtml for everything. Was initially unsure if that is semantically slightly incorrect, but it seems like the best way.